# Laravel: Getting parameters passed back from external URL

Tags: laravel, url, parameters, get

I am going to be using a third party payment solution. Once I submit the payment information, the URL will contain messages such as success code.

How can I retrieve those parameters?

I will need to pass them back to a controller so that I can use them to query other information or update the database (i.e. update the `valid` column if the url code returns the value `000`).

The response back from the payment service will look like this:

```
https://example.com/return.html?order_id=6&code=000&msg=Success&error=&mPAN=XXXXXXXXXXXX3801&name=   Salvatore%20F%20Iozzia&type=Visa&exp=1012&ApprovalCode=012345&TxnGUID=1234567890&PrcTxnID=ABCDEFG&osCsid=ddc2e76644e8dde7308d42606f7f7e74
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use Request

**EXAMPLE**:

```
$theorder_id = $request->input('order_id');
```

or you can get them together

```
$payment = $request->all();
```

and then you can access everything in the $payment variable.

**EDIT**:

Don't forget to add `Request` to your method and at the top of your controller:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request; // at the top

public function paymentexemple(Request $request) {
    $theorder_id = $request->input('order_id');
    $themsg = $request->input('msg');
    //do stuff
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Do I have to add a route for this?